# Update table column so that each row has a string plus incrementing number

Tags: mysql

Is there a SQL command to update a column in a table, something like:

```
UPDATE user_data
SET name='user' + ' ' + n
```

so that each row is updated with a string plus an incrementing number?

```
name
------
user 1
user 2
user 3
```

Comment: Wrap this in a loop and increment 'n' each time.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two statements:

```
SET @n = 0;

UPDATE user_data
SET name = CONCAT('user', ' ', (@n:=@n+1));
```

You could even combine 'user' and ' ' into one string, but I showed it as separate to make the point that CONCAT() takes any number of arguments.

By the way, `+` is a string concatenation operator in Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Access. Not in standard SQL, nor in MySQL.